# How to fix terminated due to memory issue when using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-graphics, automatic-ref-counting

In my drawing app I'm using UIImage to cache drawing on it.

The following line of code cause a memory issue:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
self.cacheImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

How can I use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` without causing memory leaks ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this may be it help you.
It help me in my case

```
 @autoreleasepool {
  // Write your code here    
 }
```